# Estimate of the $n$-th derivative of $\frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2)-2e^{-3x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

For $x > 0$ let
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2)}.
$$
I would like to estimate the $n$-th derivative of $f$. To this end I use partial fractions decomposition
$$
f(x) = \frac{2}{x+2} - \frac{1}{x+1}
$$
and easily obtain
$$
|f^{(n)}(x)| \le C n! \frac{1}{x^{n+1}},
$$
for some constant $C > 0$ (independent of $n$) and all $x > 0$.

My question is: what happens if we consider
$$
g(x) = \frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2) - 2e^{-3x}}?
$$
The function $g$ is not rational, hence we do not have partial fractions decomposition. However, numerical analysis suggest that it is possible to obtain similar estimate of the $n$-th derivative of $g$ as for $f$.

> Does there exist $D > 0$ such that for all non-negative integers $n$ and all $x > 0$ we have
> $$
> |g^{(n)}(x)| \le D n! \frac{1}{x^{n+1}}?
> $$

**Edit.** I tried the following approach: since $f$, as a complex function defined on the right-half plane ($0$ is a removable singularity), is holomorphic, by the Cauchy formula it follows that for every $x > 0$ we have
$$
f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-x)^{n+1}} dz,
$$
where $\gamma$ is any closed path around $x$. Hence, if we let $\gamma$ to be a circle with center at $x$ and radius $x$, then
$$
|f^{(n)}(x)| \le \frac{n!}{2\pi} \frac{1}{x^{n+1}} \int_\gamma |f(z)| dz.
$$
It looks promising, since $f(z)$ is bounded (say, by $M > 0$) for $\mathrm{Re}(z) \ge 0$. However, the integral is taken over the circle with length $2\pi x$, which implies
$$
|f^{(n)}(x)| \le M \frac{n!}{x^n}, \qquad x > 0.
$$
This is nice, but I would like to get the estimate of the form
$$
M \frac{n!}{x^{n+1}}.
$$
Is it somehow possible to refine this mathod to get $\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{x^n}$?

Comment: You can start by locating the complex roots of $(x+1)(x+2)-2 e^{-3x}$ and by approximating the residue of $g(x)$ at such points (simple poles).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've tried to figure this out, but I still miss something. Could you please give me more details? As far as I understand the function $(z+1)(z+2)-2e^{-3x}$ has infinite number of roots (all have non-positive real part), right? How can I estimate its residues? And what next? Should I use Mittag-Leffler's expansion?

Comment: Yes, Jack's answer is the method behind Mittag-Leffler - for simple poles the residue is nothing but the coefficient in the partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the log derivative? If $$ 
g(x) = \frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2) - 2e^{-3x}}
$$
then we can consider
$\log g(x) = \log x - \log((x+1)(x+2) - 2e^{-3x})  $
Hence
$$[\log g(x)] ' = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2) - 2e^{-3x}} \cdot (2x +3)$$
In a perhaps more helpful form
$$\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{g(x)}{x}(2x+3+6e^{-3x})$$
So bounding $g'(x)$ is reduced to the analysis of $g(x)$. Though very clunky, perhaps you could try to use induction from here on out?

Regardless, I think **Mittag-Leffler's theorem** would be much easier if you can work out the zeroes of the denominator; Weierstrass factorization guarantees this can be done.

Comment: Thanks. I tried something like that but I was not able to write the $n$-th derivative in a managable way. On the other hand, as far as I understand, Mittag-Leffler's decomposition $g(x) = G(x) + \sum (z-z_k)^{a_k}$ would be very useful, provided that I can say something about the entire function $G$. Is it possible?