# Bound the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(a+it)}{(1-ist)^n} dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives, improper-integrals, complex-integration

For
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2) - e^{-3x}}
$$
I try to prove that

> there exist $M > 0$ such that for all non-negative integers $n$ and all $x > 0$ we have
> $$
> |f^{(n)}(x)| \le M n! \frac{1}{x^{n+1}}.\tag{1}
> $$

Numerical analysis shows that it should be true. However, none of the approaches I tried (guessing a formula for the $n$-th derivative, using Cauchy's integral formula or Mittag-Leffer's decomposition) works for me. I also know that (1) is a consequence of the following:

> for all $a > 0$ there exists $K > 0$ such that for all $s > 0$ and all $n \in \{2,3,\dots\}$,
> $$
> \biggl| \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(a+it)}{(1-ist)^n} dt \biggr| \le K.
> $$

Is there a way to estimate the integral?

This question is related to [Estimate of the $n$-th derivative of $\frac{x}{(x+1)(x+2)-2e^{-3x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4472693).